# Flow control in a simple Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to make a simple game.

The logic is like this: "There are five doors, each numbered 1 to 5. Users will be asked to input any one number. For example, if they enter "1", the GoldRoom will be opened (and the associated class will be processed)."

Now, I have defined one class, `GoldRoom()`, and for testing, entered "1". The processing happens as expected. However,  when I enter "2" as my choice, the processing still happens, instead of the print statement, i.e the else statement is not getting executed.

Where am I going wrong?

```
#################################
#   Learning to make a game#
#################################

# An attempt to make a game
# Each room will be described by a class, whose base class will be Room
# The user will be prompted to enter a number, each number will be assigned with a Room in return

from sys import exit

print "Enter your choice:"
room_chosen = int(raw_input("> "))

if room_chosen == 1:
    goldroom = GoldRoom()
    goldroom.gold_room()


def dead(why):
    print "why, Good Job!"
    exit(0)

#class Room(object):  #the other room will be derived of this
#   pass

class Room(object):
    pass

class GoldRoom(Room):

    # here the user will be asked with question on how much Gold he wants

    print"This room is full of gold. How much do you take!"

    next = raw_input("> ")

    if "0" in next or "1" in next:
        how_much = int(next)
        print how_much
    else:
        dead("Man, learn to type some number")

    if how_much < 50:
        print "Nice, you are not greedy, you win!"
        exit(0)

    else:
        dead("You greedy bastard!")

#class KoiPondRoom(Room):

    # in this room, the user will be made to relax

#class Cthulhu_Room(Room):

    # sort of puzzle to get out

#class Bear_Room(Room):

    # bear room

#class Dark_Room(Room):

    # Dark Room, will  be turned into Zombie

#class Dead_Room(Room):

    # Those who enter here would be dead
if room_chosen == 1:
    goldroom = GoldRoom()
    goldroom.gold_room()
else:
    print "YOU SUCK!"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem is here:

```
class GoldRoom(Room):

    # here the user will be asked with question on how much Gold he wants

    print"This room is full of gold. How much do you take!"
```

as the whole source loaded into python vm, this piece of code is executed, and it print some thing, you should change it to:

```
class GoldRoom(Room):

    # here the user will be asked with question on how much Gold he wants
    def gold_room(self):
        print"This room is full of gold. How much do you take!"

        next = raw_input("> ")

        if "0" in next or "1" in next:
            how_much = int(next)
            print how_much
        else:
            dead("Man, learn to type some number")

        if how_much < 50:
            print "Nice, you are not greedy, you win!"
            exit(0)

        else:
            dead("You greedy bastard!")
```

Comment: oh ok, thanks for help :)..i missed that def in the class but initializing it :)

Comment: PS C:\USers\rk\lpthw> python ex45.py
Enter your choice:
> 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex45.py", line 24, in <module>
    class GoldRoom(Room):
  File "ex45.py", line 32, in GoldRoom
    if "0" in next or "1" in next:
TypeError: argument of type 'builtin_function_or_method' is not iterable

Comment: class GoldRoom(Room):

 def gold_room(self):
 
 # here the user will be asked with question on how much Gold he wants 
  print"This room is full of gold. How much do you take!" 
  next = raw_input("> ")
 
 if "0" in next or "1" in next:
  how_much = int(next)
 else:
  dead("Man, learn to type some number")
  
 if how_much < 50:
  print "Nice, you are not greedy, you win!"
  exit(0) 
 else:
  dead("You greedy bastard!")

Comment: @peterparker change >>>if "0" in next or "1" in next:<<< to >>>>if next.isdigit()<<<<

Comment: "PS C:\USers\rk\lpthw>python ex45.py
Enter your choice:> 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex45.py", line 24, in <module>
    class GoldRoom(Room):
  File "ex45.py", line 32, in GoldRoom
    if next.isdigit():
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'isdigit'
PS C:\USers\rk\lpthw> python ex45.py
Enter your choice:
> 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex45.py", line 24, in <module>
    class GoldRoom(Room):
  File "ex45.py", line 32, in GoldRoom
    if next.isdigit():
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'isdigit'

Comment: do i need to import a module() ?

Comment: thats wired, could you send your whole code to me : zhuangdaoyu(#)gmail.com

Comment: @peterparker see my last reply, send me mail